# Issue with alignment (js fiddle)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'd like to align multiple divs next to each other (horizontal centered). If there are more then n divs the container where the divs are located should be scrollable in x-direction like a simple scrollbar to get something like this:

[image: Image #1]

[image: Image #2]

[image: Image #3]

**Note**: Would somebody be so kind to add the `(!)` before the images?

---

However - I could not get it working so far using this code:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: gray;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  background-image: url("http://www.icemeltmanufacturers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/head-icon-png-5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: contain;
}

#bigContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  bottom: 0%;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="bigContainer">

    <div id="container">

      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>

    </div>


</div>
```

**Note**: It seems like Stackoverflow currently is broke for me so there is the fiddle for testing the code: https://jsfiddle.net/nfdgyx73/13/

**Note**: It would be cool to provide a solution where I don't have to apply massive changes to the containers (especially not to change their position attributes)

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? I also updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/nfdgyx73/40/

Just need to display the items inline (`display: inline-block`), and make sure you aren't wrapping your container since it is using a % to calculate width (`white-space: nowrap`), along with ensuring no overflow for container on y axis (`overflow-y: hidden`)

Per your comment, I have also added `text-align: center` to container id, so if there is less items that don't require scroll, they will center.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: gray;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  background-image: url("http://www.icemeltmanufacturers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/head-icon-png-5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  margin: 4px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: contain;
}

#bigContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  bottom: 0%;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="bigContainer">

  <div id="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but if there are only a few item these should be vertically centered.. Like I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: I see you mentioned horizontally centered, which is what I provided in the answer. If you want them to vertically stack after they reach the width threshold, then you would remove the white-space : nowrap and overflow-y: hidden..

Comment: Please have a Look at the First 2 Images. Using your solution given only one item inside the items aligns left but it should be centered! Please update your code because currently this is just a solution for a Part of my question! Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant, sorry. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Was this able to help, or the answers above? If so, please accept one of the 3 provided answers.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses flex box to align all the items as desired. If the there are more items than there is space for it adds a scrollbar (uncomment the extra divs to see it in action)

https://jsfiddle.net/nfdgyx73/58/

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 40%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  background: gray;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#container::before, #container::after {
  content: '';
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  width: 10%;
  height: 80%;
  background: url("http://www.icemeltmanufacturers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/head-icon-png-5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 0 5px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}


#bigContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: white;
  bottom: 0%;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="bigContainer">

  <div id="container">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>

    <!-- <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div> -->

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `position: absolute;` isn't necessary, this could be done with flexboxes

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: -webkit-fit-available;
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
}

#container .item {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#container .item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url("http://www.icemeltmanufacturers.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/head-icon-png-5.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
}

#bigContainer {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* This is just to help differentiate the two bigContainers */
}
```

```html
<div id="bigContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bigContainer">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```